# How to run BIRT reports in a java application?

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

I designed report by BIRT on eclipse and I can run it from run button how can I run it be java code?

Comment: Your question is not precise enough. What do you want to do with the report? View it in a Web application? Or generate a PDF file?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the configuration part needs to be done.
Include all jars from the `web-inf\lib` directory of the runtime into your own `webapp\web-inf\lib` directory.

Then comes the part of configuration of servlet in your web.xml something like this.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>EngineServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtEngineServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EngineServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/output</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Viewer Tag Library defination:

```
<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/birt.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tlds/birt.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

There are other settings that can be included in web.xml for controlling the behaviour of your web viewer.
Few are as below:

```
   BIRT_VIEWER_LOCALE:This setting sets the default locale for the Web Viewer.
    BIRT_VIEWER_MAX_ROWS: Specifies the maximum number of rows to retrieve from a dataset.
    BIRT_RESOURCE_PATH: This setting specifies the resource path used by report engine. The resource path is used to search for libraries, images, and properties files used by a report. If this setting is left blank, resources will be searched for in the same directory as the report.
```

Other can be learnt from BIRT portal.
 Below is the example in JSP Page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
                    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
                    <%@ taglib uri="/birt.tld" prefix="birt" %>
                    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
                    <html>
                    <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
                    <title>Insert title here</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                    <birt:viewer id="birtViewer" reportDesign="myReport.rptdesign"
                    pattern="frameset"
                    height="450"
                    width="700"
                    format="html">
                    </birt:viewer>
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

Provide a menu for your report in web appliucation and your report is ready to run. :-)